# telerik kendo treeview - prevent dragging outside of parent

Tags: drag-and-drop, telerik, treeview, kendo-ui

I'm trying to prevent the dragging and dropping of nodes outside of the parent node ("LLCA") with no luck.

Any suggestions?

[Image of Treeview](http://www.apartmenthost.com/images/capture.png)

I ended up getting it to work using your code below:

```
function onDrop(e) {
    var dst = e.destinationNode;
    var first = $('.k-item:first');
    var pos = e.dropPosition;
    if (dst && dst.uid === first.uid && pos !== "over") {
        e.setValid(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets define the `treeview`:

```
var tree = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource :content,
    dragAndDrop:true
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

What I'm going to do is add a `drop` callback where I will control that:

1. We are not dropping outside the tree
2. We are not dropping before or after the first node of the tree

The definition of the tree would be:

```
var tree = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource :content,
    dragAndDrop:true,
    drop       :function (ev) {
        var dst = tree.dataItem(ev.destinationNode);
        var first = tree.dataItem(".k-item:first");
        var pos = ev.dropPosition;
        if (dst && dst.uid === first.uid && pos !== "over") {
            console.log("invalid");
            ev.setValid(false);
        }
    }
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Check http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#drop for information on `drop` event.

Comment: How could I do this if I'm using the MVC wrappers?

`code`
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView().....
`code`


I can capture the drag event using this:
`code`
$(".k-treeview").data("kendoTreeView").bind("drop", function (e) {

        });
`code`

Comment: @OnaBai can you please confirm **setValid function** on kendo 2015 Q2 (it's not working, and probably a bug) it's working on kendo 2015 SP 1, SP 2 though.

Comment: @OnaBai    Question :   what is  "uid?"

Comment: @TomStickel uid stands for Unique Identifier

Answer (score 2):

Because I cannot comment on an answer, I will write my own.

User Mithrilhall asked about MVC wrappers, also the top answer only prevents movement to the root node.

I will attempt to answer both Mithrilhall and provide an example where you can only move a child within the context of its parent.  To put it another way, to only allow children of any parent to change their order within the parent.

Firstly, for MithrilHall, this is how you get to the events in MVC.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
            .Name("ourTreeView")
            .Events(e => e.Drop("treeViewDrop"))
```

There are other events in treeview, you can take a gander for yourself.  The argument is the name of a javascript function.  Here is an example javascript function for this MVC wrapper to prevent children from moving outside of their parent, but allowing them to still move within the parent.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function treeViewDrop(dropEvent) {
        var treeView = $("#ourTreeView").data("kendoTreeView");
        var destination = treeView.dataItem(dropEvent.destinationNode);
        var source = treeView.dataItem(dropEvent.sourceNode);

        if (!(destination && destination.parentID == source.parentID)) {
            dropEvent.setValid(false);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I had a parentID field modeled in my datasource.  You could accomplish this in many ways.  The dataItem method returns a kendo treeview item, so it has all of your modeled fields in it.

Also understand, this solution does not change the widget to show an X when you are moving to a place you cannot drop to.  This is another problem with another solution.

I hope this helps, good luck!